# em.getTransaction().commit(); causing an error in jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

ive been getting the following errors when trying parser a xml file to mysql database.The database is created.
I dont under stand why it cannot create the user

error code
    [Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzh0A.png)

Driver.java

```
package DAO;

import parser.XMLParser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import entities.*;

public class NewDriver {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();

    ProductDAO productDAO= new ProductDAO();
    ProductOnHandDAO productOnHandDAO= new ProductOnHandDAO();
    XMLParser x = new XMLParser();

    User user1 = new User("luke", "luke");
    userDAO.createUser(user1);

    Store store = new Store();
    StoreDAO storeDAO= new StoreDAO();
    storeDAO.createStore(store);


    List<Product> products = x.getProduct("‪test.xml");
    for(Product p : products){
        p.setStore(store);
        productDAO.createProduct(p);
    }

    List<Product> productList = ProductDAO.findByStore(store);
    List<ProductOnHand>productOnHands;

    productOnHands = x.getAllProductOnHand(productList,"‪test.xml");
    for (ProductOnHand p1 : productOnHands){
        p1.setStore(store);
        ProductOnHandDAO.createProductOnHand(p1);

    }


}
}
```

UserDAO.java

```
public class UserDAO {

 public void createUser(User user){
        PersistenceUtil.persist(user);
    }

    public List<User> findAllUsers(){
        EntityManager em = PersistenceUtil.createEM();
        List<User> users = (List<User>)
                em.createNamedQuery("User.findAllUsers").getResultList();
        em.close();
        return users;
    }

     public User findUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String 
      password){
        EntityManager em = PersistenceUtil.createEM();
        List<User> users = (List<User>)






   em.createNamedQuery("User.findUserByUsernameAndPassword").
   setParameter("username", username).setParameter("password", 
   password).getResultList();
        em.close();
        return users.get(0);
    }
 }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@Column
private int id;

private String username;
private String password;


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}


public User() {
}
}
```

Persistence.util

```
public class PersistenceUtil implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected static EntityManagerFactory emf =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dt354rel");


public static void persist(Object entity) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(entity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}

public static void remove(Object entity) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Object mergedEntity = em.merge(entity);
    em.remove(mergedEntity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}

public static Object merge(Object entity) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    entity = em.merge(entity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return entity;
}

public static EntityManager createEM() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

}
```

Any help would be appricated i looked at my persistence class and it all seems fine to me.

Comment: Put the errors IN THE QUESTION, not on some random remote site!

Comment: Have you got a solution to help me or are you just here to tell me that?

Comment: Kindly read the FAQ of the site about how to pose a question, and it will tell you to include ALL pertinent details IN THE QUESTION. You want to ignore that and demand "give me the answer". That is unlikely to have success unless you follow the very reasonable info here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error:

```
Table dt354rel.user doesn't exist
```

Check if this table is missing or if you don't have access to that table.

Btw. you don't have to create a new EntityManager in all that methods. You could create it once an reuse it.